# Castle Windsor upgrade causes TypeLoadException for generic types

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have the following mapping in my Castle Windsor xml file which has worked okay (unchanged) for some time:

```
<component id="defaultBasicRepository"
           service="MyApp.Models.Repositories.IBasicRepository`1, MyApp.Models"
           type="MyApp.Models.Repositories.Linq.BasicRepository`1, MyApp.Models"
           lifestyle="perWebRequest"/>
```

I got this from the Windsor documentation at http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v1rc3/usersguide/genericssupport.html.

Since I upgraded Windsor, I now get the following exception at runtime:

> **Description:** An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> **Exception Details:**
>   System.TypeLoadException:
>   GenericArguments[0], 'T', on 'MyApp.Models.Repositories.Linq.BasicRepository`1[TEntity]'
>   violates the constraint of type parameter 'TEntity'.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> Line 44: public static void ConfigureIoC()
>   Line 45: {
>   Line 46:     var windsor = new WindsorContainer("Windsor.xml");
>   Line 47:
>   Line 48:     ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(windsor));

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 1.0, Visual Studio 2008 and Castle Windsor as downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/InversionOfControl/2.1/Castle-Windsor-2.1.1.zip/download

Can anyone shed any light on this?  I'm sure the upgrade of Castle Windsor is what caused it - it's been working well for ages.

**UPDATE**:
I fixed it myself in the end.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962214/castle-windsor-upgrade-causes-typeloadexception-for-generic-types#2962315) below for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer for myself in the end, by comparing all the classes/interfaces in the mapping.

The answer was that the `BasicRepository`'s generic type argument had a generic constraint as follows:

```
public class BasicRepository<TEntity> : IBasicRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
```

...but the interface that it implemented didn't have the same constraint:

```
public interface IBasicRepository<T>
{
```

I updated the interface to match:

```
public interface IBasicRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
```

and now everything works fine.

Hope this helps someone. :)